# How do I get my booking button to display the correct flight information on my booking page?

Tags: php, html

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){

    $origin = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['origin']);
    $destination = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['going']);
    $depart = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['depart']);
    $arrival = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['arrival']);
    $students = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Guests']);
    $students = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['price']);


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM flightsearch.form 
             WHERE form.origin LIKE '%$origin%'
             OR form.destination LIKE '%$destination%'
             OR form.depart LIKE '%depart%' 
             OR form.arrival LIKE '%arrival%' 
             OR form.students LIKE '%students%' 
              ";


    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($queryResult > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            var_dump($row);
            echo "

             <tr>
             <th>Origin</th>
             <td>".$row['origin']."</td>  

             </tr>

             <tr>
             <th>Destination</th>
             <td>
             ".$row['destination']."
             </td>
             </tr>


             <tr>
             <th>Departing</th>
             <td>
             ".$row['depart']."
             </td>
             </tr>

             <tr>
             <th>Arrival</th>
             <td>
            ".$row['arrival']."
             </td>
             </tr>

             <tr>
             <th>Students</th>
             <td>
             ".$row['students']."   
             </td>



             <tr>
             <td>
```

How do I get this button to take me to the `booking.php` page displaying the correct information selected.

```
         ***<button type='submit' id='btn-res' name='book'>
             Book</button>***
             </td>
             </tr>

            </tr>        
            ";
        }
    }else{
        echo "No results found";
    }


}
```

Right now all information is getting displayed. My problem is assigning the button to the correct information within my database.[Here is the output so far]

[image]

The button in the image should take me to a page displaying the following

```
Origin  London - Heathrow
Destination Barcelona
Departing   2018-03-04 03:00:00
Arrival 2018-02-04 07:00:00
Students    2"
```

I am a beginner in php so please don't be too critical of my work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most common thing in this situation is as follows:

Next to each result you put a hyperlink (not a button) which, when clicked, will take the user to a booking details page. You can pass the ID of the flight as a querystring parameter so that it knows which flight the user clicked on.

e.g. an example would look like:

```
<a href="booking.php?flightID=23">Book</a>
```

To code that using PHP and inject the correct ID, you'd use something like:

```
<a href="booking.php?flightID=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Book</a>
```

Then in the `booking.php` script you'd check for the ID something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET["flightID"])) {
  $flightID = $_GET["flightID"];
 //and then fetch the data for that flight and display the details
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! How would I fetch the data for that flight? The same way I did previously in the code above?

Comment: Well not quite, because that searches for lots of flights. But yes you'd fetch that specific record from the database. Likely you'd run a select with a WHERE clause which references the ID field specifically. I don't know your data but something like `SELECT * FROM flightsearch.form WHERE ID = ?` and then pass in `$flightID` as the parameter.

Comment: I tried the following: if(isset($_GET['flightId']))

$flightId = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["flightId"]);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM flightsearch.form WHERE form.id = '%$flightId%' ";

Comment: Ok well like I said I don't know your data structure, but that sounds plausible, although since you're searching for a specific ID, you don't need the `%` symbols (they're just used with `LIKE` in order to allow a match to only a part of the field), and also if `id` is in integer field in your database, don't put it inside quote marks. I think you maybe need to study some basic SQL, because that's quite a simple thing you should know.